# How can I modify Enchanting Rules?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-modding

TL;DR is there a way to modify the enchantments that equipment can receive from an Enchanting Table?

- Working on a ["lazy" addon](https://github.com/thebearup/lazy_minecraft_shortcuts) that simplifies some things I do often.
- One big time waster is trying to get the right enchantments (i.e. keep getting the wrong type of Protection, or Bane of Arthropods instead of Sharpness).
- I'd like to remove some of those undesired enchantments from the logic so that only the ones I actually use will appear on the enchanting table.

I see a few ways to go about this, but none are very good...

1. Modify the game's internal rules for which enchantments apply to which equipment types. This isn't surfaced anywhere in the "Vanilla" packs, so it seems to be impossible.
2. Create a new option for [`minecraft:enchantable`](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/items/items-16.html#enchantable-slots) that has the enchantments I want (i.e. `"slot": "sword2"` which has Sharpness but not Smite). Would then modify each type of equipment to use the new "slots." This is also not present in the Vanilla packs and seems to be impossible.
3. Create a new type of table which uses some functions to apply some enchantments.

#3 seems like the only method that's possible in Bedrock.
And yes, I know I can use command-blocks/NPCs to give me a sword with Sharpness level 9000 :). I'm just trying to smooth over the edges of the core gameplay (and learn a bit along the way), not completely reinvent it.

--- Edit ---

Well, I found a partial workaround

- Created an [mcfunction](https://github.com/thebearup/lazy_minecraft_shortcuts/blob/master/BP/functions/lesserenchant.mcfunction) that does the right stuff

  - Currently targeting all players (@a) while I troubleshoot.
- If I run it with /function it works
- If I run it via a command block, it works
- But if I tie it to a custom block via 'on_interact' it only partially works. The sound and particle effects play, even my levels are drained, but the enchantment doesn't happen. It seems somehow tied to the context in which the block is executing. But I tried various methods to "target" any/all players and it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who encounters this...

- I found no straight-forward way to modify enchanting rules in any way (create a new category, modify existing categories, etc).
- I also found no way to make a block target a player for enchantments. Everything else worked, just not enchantments.
- For enchantments, it seems you need a dialog, which lets you target `@initiator`. But this requires an NPC.
- There also seems to be no way to create an NPC with a pre-canned `dialog`. You must go into creative mode and set it in-game.
- So my [solution](https://github.com/thebearup/lazy_minecraft_shortcuts/blob/master/BP/blocks/lesser_enchanting_table.json) uses a block which summons an NPC when you place it. When you interact with the block, it triggers a dialog (tied to the nearby NPC). Targeting the NPC results in an empty dialog (see previous bullet) so not ideal, but at least it "works."
- While I'm ultimately pleased with the result, it's a far cry from what I set out to do, and greatly deterred by the unnecessary limitations inherent to Bedrock. If you really want to make content, just target Java.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and sharing your results.